# Better error message when missing required fields from request

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, protorpc

When missing a required field currently ProtoRPC returns a message like this:

```
{
 "error": {
  "code": 400, 
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global", 
    "message": "Error parsing ProtoRPC request (Unable to parse request content: Message CombinedContainer is missing required field api_key)", 
    "reason": "badRequest"
   }
  ], 
  "message": "Error parsing ProtoRPC request (Unable to parse request content: Message CombinedContainer is missing required field api_key)"
 }
}
```

Is it possible to provide a better error message? Ideally, "missing required field api_key" in this example.

According to the [Google Code Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/endpoints-proto-datastore/issues/detail?id=56) and [Github issues](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-proto-datastore/issues/4) this was once being worked on. However, there does not appear to be any activity.

I'd greatly appreciate any solutions or workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, the ProtoRPC still returns the same unraised error which makes it harder for one to return a customized error response.

A simple workaround is to make the Message fields optional and enforce the requirement constraint somewhere in the endpoint handler/method.

So instead of;

```
class Request(Message):
    name = StringField(1, required=True)
```

Set 'name' as optional,

```
class Request(Message):
    name = StringField(1)
```

The requirement constraint can then be enforced in the endpoint handler method by simple if statements OR by mapping these fields to a Datastore entity that requires these fields, hence will allow exception handling of BadValueError and return a more customized error response.

Example:

```
try:
    account = Account(name=request.name)
    account.put()
except BadValueError:
    return Response(status=False, message='Missing field "name"')
```